# Apple Mach Linker Not found,Missing dependency Rreact

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

After running react-native link to link all needed libraries, Xcode doesn't build the iOS version of the project. The problem is from react-native-vector-icons library being linked.

I am using .workspace file and using the Podfile to manage the dependencies for the iOS. I have tried both manual linking and react-native link for the library but the error i get is

> ld: framework not found React clang: error: linker command failed with
>   exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

```
`Showing Recent Messages
Ld /Users/../ProjectX-agmovfcichistxhkaamivrarvpqp/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/RNVectorIcons/RNVectorIcons.framework/RNVectorIcons normal x86_64
    cd /../ios/Pods
    export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=9.0
    export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch x86_64 -dynamiclib -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator12.2.sdk -L/../ProjectX-agmovfcichistxhkaamivrarvpqp/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/RNVectorIcons -F/../ProjectX-agmovfcichistxhkaamivrarvpqp/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/RNVectorIcons -F/../ProjectX-agmovfcichistxhkaamivrarvpqp/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/DoubleConversion -F/../ProjectX-agmovfcichistxhkaamivrarvpqp/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Folly -F/../ProjectX-agmovfcichistxhkaamivrarvpqp/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/React -F/../ProjectX-agmovfcichistxhkaamivrarvpqp/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/glog -F/../ProjectX-agmovfcichistxhkaamivrarvpqp/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/yoga -filelist /../ProjectX-agmovfcichistxhkaamivrarvpqp/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/RNVectorIcons.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/RNVectorIcons.LinkFileList -install_name @rpath/RNVectorIcons.framework/RNVectorIcons -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @executable_path/Frameworks -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @loader_path/Frameworks -mios-simulator-version-min=9.0 -dead_strip -Xlinker -object_path_lto -Xlinker /../ProjectX-agmovfcichistxhkaamivrarvpqp/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/RNVectorIcons.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/RNVectorIcons_lto.o -Xlinker -export_dynamic -Xlinker -no_deduplicate -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -fprofile-instr-generate -framework Foundation -framework React -compatibility_version 1 -current_version 1 -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /../ProjectX-agmovfcichistxhkaamivrarvpqp/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/RNVectorIcons.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/RNVectorIcons_dependency_info.dat -o /../ProjectX-agmovfcichistxhkaamivrarvpqp/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/RNVectorIcons/RNVectorIcons.framework/RNVectorIcons

ld: framework not found React
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
`
```

I expect a successful build for the iOS.

Comment: Hi @lutakyn , have you found a solution?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that `react-native-link` should never be run on its own, for it causes breaks more than actually doing anything.

1. Reset your project's configuration, i.e. unlink and uninstall all dependencies, and delete the `ios/build` folder.
2. After installing them again, if you insist on using automatic linking, then run `react-native link <library_name>` for each one.
3. Alternatively, you could try the manual linking process.

#### IOS Manual Library Installation Steps

- add the `.xcodeproj` of the component to the Libraries folder in XCode
- add the `lib{library_name}.a` file to Linked Frameworks and Libraries under the General section in Target Project.

#### Additional Notes

- Make sure you have checked that the font is copied in the Copy Bundle Resources in Build Phases. If not, re-check the manual configuration steps.
- Make sure you kill the packager and re-run for changes to take effect.

Comment: Ok I will try that as well